# Fast way to check against link rot in a MW wiki?

Tags: mediawiki

I was using [extension ExternalLinks](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:ExternalLinks) to check external links per page. However it's now marked unsafe and is no longer maintained. What quick and easy ways are  there to validate all external URLs on a MW wiki?

Answer (score 1):

Wikimedia uses the [DeadlinkChecker](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/DeadlinkChecker) library. I don't think there is any extension wrapping it at this time but maybe you can use it to resurrect ExternalLinks.